# Calling constructor with string argument passing char * report error

Tags: c++, string, implicit-conversion, stdstring

```cpp
template<typename T>
class SharedValue {
public:
    SharedValue(const T& t): valuePtr(new T(t)) {}
    
    const SharedValue& operator = (const T &t) {
        *valuePtr = t;
        return *this;
    }
  
protected:
    dd_shared_ptr<T> valuePtr;
};

typedef SharedValue<std::string> SharedString;
 
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // compile succeeded
    SharedString str(argv[0]);

    // compile failed:
    SharedString str2 = argv[0];
   
    return 0;
}
```

The `str2` construction failed, reporting:

> ```
> No viable conversion from 'const char *' to 'SharedString' (aka 'SharedValue<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>>')
> ```

Why `str` succeeded whereas `str2` failed, is there any difference?

Comment: you didn't wrote conversion constructor that takes this type of argument. Implicit conversion won't work here, you need initializer list for that to happen. `SharedString str2 = {argv[0]};`

Comment: Must watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why str succeeded whereas str2 failed, is there any difference?

Yes, there is difference between the two. In particular, in `str` we have have **direct initialization** while in `str2` we have **copy initialization**.

The behavior of your program can be understood from [copy initialization documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) which states:

> In addition, the implicit conversion in *copy-initialization* **must produce `T` directly from the initializer**, while, e.g. *direct-initialization* **expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of `T`'s constructor.**

(emphasis mine)

Now let's apply this to your given example on case by case basis.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
SharedString str2 = argv[0]; //this is copy initialization
```

The above uses **copy initialization**. And as `SharedString` can't be directly produced from the **initializer** of type `const char*` on the right hand side since it requires an implicit conversion, this case 1 isn't allowed in accordance with the above quoted statement.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
SharedString str(argv[0]); //this is direct initialization
```

while the above uses **direct initialization** and since there is an *implicit conversion available*(using the **converting constructor**), this time it is allowed according to the above quoted statement.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Are you confusing `SharedString str2 = argv[0];` with `SharedString str2 = {argv[0]};`? That is, are you saying that `SharedString str2 = argv[0];` is not copy initialization?  Note also that OP used `SharedString str2 = argv[0];` in the original qestion which is **copy initialization** while you suggested  the latter `SharedString str2 = {argv[0]};` which is **copy-list initialization** from C++11. Again OP didn't use the latter so i don't see what is your point in writing the comment above.